# How can I create an environment to test OpenVPN with in a test lab?

Tags: openvpn, linux-networking

I have a test lab that I would like to use to test a site-to-site VPN setup with using OpenVPN. What is the minimum amount of hardware that I need and how should it be configured so that I can mimic a real-world scenerio?

Comment: *All* questions relating to things in a home setting are off-topic. I've edited this question to try and save it. Please read our [faq] and keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You would need at least 4 devices if you want to run the OpenVPN tunnels on the same devices that are also acting as the edge routers.

```
|Client1|----network1----|router1/openVPN|-----network2----|router2/OpenVPN|----network3----|Client2|
```

This is a bit of a crude drawing, but you get the point. Each router needs two interfaces. One that connects to each internal network and one that connects to each other on what would be analagous to a WAN link.

Comment: Thanks!! Is network2 the tunnel? I... think I did this. I got it to work, but my problem is that I cannot ping other pc's on the server vpn server side network. I am trying to use static routes, do I have do do bridging to achive connection to other clients besides the vpnserver?

Comment: Network 2 is just another network that the tunnel traverses. In a lab environment, this can just be a single cable that connects the two routers. In practice, it will likely be the Internet.

Comment: @SuperJason You can use bridging or routing. Depends on how you want it configured.